# Error al subir imagenes en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un blog en Laravel, los posts tienen imágenes y al crear un post se sube una imagen. Si se crea el post la imagen se sube perfectamente pero cuando se edita el post y se sube otra imagen esta no se sube y ademas la direccion en la base de datos cambia a algo como esto:

C:\xampp\tmp\phpCC3D.tmp

adjunto el código del controlador de los posts:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;  
use App\Http\Requests\PostStoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\PostUpdateRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


use App\Post;
use App\Category;
use App\Tag;

class PostController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->paginate();


    return view('admin.posts.index', compact('posts'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->pluck('name', 'id');
    $tags       = Tag::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();

     return view('admin.posts.create', compact('categories', 'tags'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(PostStoreRequest $request)
{
    //validacion
    $post = Post::create($request->all());

    //IMAGE
    if($request->file('file')){
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image', $request->file('file'));

        $post->fill(['file' => asset($path)])->save();
    }

    //TAGS
    $post->tags()->sync($request->get('tags'));

    return redirect()->route('posts.edit', $post->id)
        ->with('info', 'Entrada creada con exito');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $this->authorize('pass', $post);

    return view('admin.posts.show', compact('post'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $post       = Post::find($id);
    $this->authorize('pass', $post);

    $categories = Category::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->pluck('name', 'id');
    $tags       = Tag::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();

    return view('admin.posts.edit', compact('post', 'categories', 'tags'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(PostUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $this->authorize('pass', $post);
    $post->fill($request->all())->save();

    //IMAGE 
    if($request->file('image')){
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image',  $request->file('image'));
        $post->fill(['file' => asset($path)])->save();
    }

    //TAGS
    $post->tags()->sync($request->get('tags'));

    return redirect()->route('posts.edit', $post->id)->with('info', 'Entrada actualizada con éxito');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $this->authorize('pass', $post);
    $post->delete();

    return back()->with('info', 'Eliminado correctamente');
}
}
```

Lo que considero debo cambiar en el código es la parte del update, solo que no veo como agregarle para que elimine la imagen anterior:

```
 public function update(PostUpdateRequest $request, $id)
 {
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $this->authorize('pass', $post);
    $post->fill($request->all())->save();

    //IMAGE 
    if($request->file('image')){
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image',  $request->file('image'));
        $post->fill(['file' => asset($path)])->save();
    }

    //TAGS
    $post->tags()->sync($request->get('tags'));

    return redirect()->route('posts.edit', $post->id)->with('info', 'Entrada actualizada con éxito');
}
```

¿Que debo cambiar en el código para borrar la imagen ya existente y subir la nueva?

**Edit1:** Pude resolverlo, el problema era aqui:

```
public function update(PostUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
$post = Post::find($id);
$this->authorize('pass', $post);
$post->fill($request->all())->save();

//IMAGE 
if($request->file('image')){
    $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image',  $request->file('image'));
    $post->fill(['file' => asset($path)])->save();
}
```

Realmente debería ser asi:

```
public function update(PostUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
$post = Post::find($id);
$this->authorize('pass', $post);
$post->fill($request->all())->save();

//IMAGE 
if($request->file('file')){
    $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image',  $request->file('file'));
    $post->fill(['file' => asset($path)])->save();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veo que usas muchos de features que Laravel proporciona; pero hay unos cuantos que te podría servir mucho más para lo que estás haciendo, a continuación trataré de explicártelos.

---

## Filesystem

Primero que nada, debemos de entender algo ¿guardarás con frecuencia imágenes en el sistema? Si es así es conveniente utilizar el `Local Disk` que Laravel proporciona, este no es por default y por lo cual debemos modificar el archivo de configuraciones del `filesystem` de Laravel.

Una vez hecho esto, cada vez que queramos efectuar cambios en disco; sea mediante `Request` o la facade `Storage`, todos estos cambios se efectuarán en el disco público sin tener la necesidad de especificar que disco queremos seleccionar.

Todo lo que te acabo de comentar es completamente opcional, queda a tu criterio usarlo o no, pero cabe destacar que los ejemplos de código que usaré tendrán en cuenta dichos cambios.

---

### File storage usando `Request`

Creo que este es uno de los features que más me han gustado de Laravel 5.3, la capacidad de utilizar la misma `Request` para guardar archivos da una flexibilidad increíble al momento de guardar archivos.

#### Función store

```
public function store(PostStoreRequest $request)
{
    // Crea la instancia del post.
    $post = Post::create($request->all());

    // Guarda la imagen en el disco público.
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $path = $request->file('file')->store('image');

        // Es importante guardar el path del archivo, más adelante
        // explicaré el por qué.
        $post->file = $path;
    }

    // Tags
    $post->tags()->sync($request->get('tags'));

    return redirect()->route('posts.edit', $post->id)
        ->with('info', 'Entrada creada con exito');
}
```

Para guardar archivos usando `Request`, únicamente nos tenemos que asegura que exista un archivo a guardar y por supuesto las validaciones propuestas que desees aplicar a dicho archivo, para ello veo que has usado un `FormRequest` que es justamente una buena forma de validar datos.

#### Función update

```
function update(PostUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
    // Es necesario lanzar una excepción si no encontramos el modelo.
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $this->authorize('pass', $post);

    // No es necesario guardar en este punto, ya que aún nos quedan
    // operaciones por realizar en el modelo.
    $post->fill($request->all());

    // Lógica para eliminar y guardar la nueva imágen.
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        // Se toma el path de la imagen anterior y se elimina, nota
        // que es necesario usar el path relativo al sistema de archivos
        // en vez de usar el path completo del servidor, para ello es necesario
        // guardar el archivo sin usar la función asset().
        Storage::delete($post->file);

        // Se guarda el nuevo archivo y se asigna a su respectivo modelo.
        $path = $request->file('image')->store('image');
        $post->file = $path;
    }

    // Una vez terminadas las operaciones podemos guardar.
    $post->save();

    // Tags
    $post->tags()->sync($request->get('tags'));

    return redirect()->route('posts.edit', $post->id)->with('info', 'Entrada actualizada con éxito');
}
```

---

### ¿Por qué no es necesario usar la función `asset()` al momento de guardar o actualizar el modelo?

Laravel provee una increíble cantidad de features out of the box que podemos sacar provecho, una de mis favoritas son los `Accessors` y los valores agregados.

Los `Accessors` a grandes rasgos son funciones que se ejecutan al momento de obtener propiedades de un modelo; por ejemplo, si nosotros quisiéramos que el nombre de un usuario estuviera en mayúsculas sin modificar su integridad en la DB un `Accessor` sería una muy buena opción.

Para más información te recomiendo que le des un vistazo a la documentación de Laravel:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Si nosotros definimos un `Accessor` en el modelo `Post`, por ejemplo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

// Estos datos sólo existirán en la serialización, eso
// significa que no necesitaremos modificar la base de datos
// para agregar este campo, ya que el Accessor se encargará de
// asignarle un valor cada vez que usemos por ejemplo $post->file_url,
// Laravel automáticamente se encagará de llamar la función
// getFileUrlAttribute cada vez que intentemos acceder a la propiedad
// file_url, por ende estos datos nunca existirán en la bd, lo cual es muy conveniente.
protected $appends = ['file_url'];

// Nos arrojará la dirección completa del archivo relativo a la dirección del servidor.
public function getFileUrlAttribute() {
    return Storage::url($this->attributes['file']);
}
```

Todas las operaciones que realicemos usando la propiedad `file_url` serán ejecutadas mediante la función `getFileUrlAttribute()`, la razón de por qué separamos la URL y la dirección del archivo es porque el sistema de archivos siempre trabaja relativo a su dirección en disco.

Es decir, que si nosotros tratamos de borrar un archivo usando la dirección que arroja la función `asset()`, ejemplo: `www.tu-sitio-web.com/images/tu-imagen-en-disco.jpeg`

El ejemplo anterior nos mandaría error si tratamos de usar `Storage::delete($path)`, ya que esperaría como entrada: `/images/ tu-imagen-en-disco.jpeg`

Claro que esto se puede resolver con expresiones regulares o inclusive usando ciclos, pero creo más conveniente y poderoso sacar provecho de las funciones que Laravel nos trae desde un principio.

Si nosotros tratamos de usar, por ejemplo `$post->file`, obtendríamos `/images/ tu-imagen-en-disco.jpeg` y si tratamos de usar `$post->file_url` obtendríamos `www.tu-sitio-web.com/images/tu-imagen-en-disco.jpeg` lo cual nos deja una manera muy eficiente de poder usar estos datos sin necesidad de realizar transformaciones en la vista o en JavaScript (si usamos como API Laravel), estos valores existen tanto en `JSON` como en `PHP`, así que no hay necesidad de preocuparnos de que no estén presentes en nuestras transformaciones.

Te recomiendo que cheques:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization

Espero haber resuelto tu problema y aclarar algunas dudas que pudieran haber surgido.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo hago lo siguiente, espero te sirva:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $logoName = $this->updateLogo($request);
    $request->merge(['logo' => $logoName]);
}

$user->update($request->all());
```

Solo te haría falta escribir una condición para eliminar la imagen.

```
public function updateLogo($request)
{
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    if ($request->user()['logo'] != null) {
        \Storage::delete('images/logos/'.$request->user()['logo']);
    }

    $file->storeAs('images/logos', $name);
    return $name;
}
```